# Add service reference failed

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, service-reference

I hosted my wcf using iis 7.0, the url is:

```
https://example.com/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc
```

when i add service reference in vs2008, got this errors:

```
The document at the url https://example.com/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'https://el-cust-port01/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc?disco'.'.
  - Unable to connect to the remote server
  - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 59.37.71.86:443
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'https://193.91.152.191/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=UTF-8').'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://193.91.152.191/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://193.91.152.191/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

My web.config is

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeName="My"  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="TESTCERT" storeLocation="LocalMachine"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="EV.Services.CustomerService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" contract="EV.Contracts.ICustomer" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are also missing a Metadata Excahnge (mex) endpoint. Try adding:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

underneath your existing endpoint. You should be able to open a web browser to:

> https://193.91.152.191/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc?wsdl

and see the actual WSDL file displayed.

Comment: hi rally, you are super man, it works for me used your code. but i got another issue when i invoke the method: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority '193.91.152.191'.

Comment: i searched it and got a solution using below code: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnValidationCallback);`
 `public static bool OnValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true;
        }`

Comment: You can find a list of all the changes need to make a wcf service work over https here. It looks like that one was the only one you were missing.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting that at home? The error basically says that you can't reach the IP address, which I can. That might be a router not supporting "nat loopback", so you can't access your external IP address from inside your network. Try adding the reference by its local IP address.

Comment: no, it's a public ip, you can access via https://193.91.152.191/CustPortal/CustomerService.svc?wsdl, but cannot add service reference in vs2008.

Answer (score 0):

add the server's hostname and IP address of the webservice in your local pc's hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)